# Grails - inetAddress - Error

Tags: java, grails

I am having some simple statement, please guide me, what is the problem.

```
String localhostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

I am getting error this:

```
Loading Grails 2.3.0.M1 | Error There was an error loading the
BuildConfig: mysystem-lnx:
Temporary failure in name resolution (NOTE: Stack trace has been
filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.net.UnknownHostException: mysystem-lnx : Temporary failure in
name resolution     at java_net_InetAddress$getLocalHost.call(Unknown
Source)     at
BuildConfig$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(BuildConfig.groovy:65)    at
BuildConfig$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(BuildConfig.groovy)   at
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at BuildConfig$_run_closure1.doCall(BuildConfig.groovy:59)  at
BuildConfig$_run_closure1.doCall(BuildConfig.groovy)    at
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
at
grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1240)
at
grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1186)
at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1082)
at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1046)
at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1024)
at
org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysystem-lnx:
Temporary failure in name resolution    ... 15 more | Error There was an
error loading the BuildConfig: mysystem-lnx:
mysystem-lnx: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Looks like a dns/hosts issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to solve it. It is happening only in my Linux only. In my friends Linux it working fine. So,

I just added try catch block.